# Portlets - Keeping session alive from server side

Tags: java, spring, session, portlet

I am implementing jsr 186 portlets, with some servlets to the mix to implement some ajax. The problem is if I only make AJAX calls for some time, I lose the session. Strangely, keeping alive the servlet session does not prevent the portlet session from timing out.

Is there a way I can keep the session alive from within my servlets, on the server side?

FWIW I'm using spring and spring mvc/portlet.

Thanks,
Miguel Ping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented it using a javascript timer that kept polling a portlet url. The portlet url was generated beforehadn so it was accessible in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. (Using OpenPortal Portlet Container)

As I know there is two different sessions, 1- portlet session, 2- Container session.

I created a simple portlet and made request to the portlet with ajax periodically from container.  However, session times out. My code fraction is here:

```
<%
    int per=15000; //ms
    String sessionExtenderPath = "http://portal.abc.com.tr:8080/SessionExtend/SessionExtend";
    //This is a portlet which includes servlet that returns a simple string.
%>

<script>
    periyod=100;

    function invokeRequest(){
     $.get("< %=sessionExtenderPath% >", function(data) {
      alert(1);
     });
    }
    window.setInterval("invokeRequest()",periyod);
</script>
```

I have solved my problem by requesting container page (wihout defining a channel for a portlet).

Thanks for edit.